# DataTables JQuery & filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, sumoselect.js

I've my table and i just want to filter with a multiselect. So i use sumoselect : http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/sumoselect_demo.html
Then, i get the selected options of my select and i want to refresh my table with this values so i do :

```
$('#ticketDataTable').DataTable();
$('#ticketDataTable').DataTable().column(5).search(pattern,true,true).draw();
```

For example pattern = "INITIAL|SECOND" but when i do that i take just my first value and no both !

Comment: It does appear to work the way you want it to. [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9wrt3yy/). Maybe there is something else wrong?

Comment: What else is happening? Is the table actually filtering? Are you actually building the `pattern` correctly? Can we see the code where you get the `pattern` variable?

Comment: I get my selected options :

var arr = $("table#ticketDataTable thead tr th#multiSelectFilter").find("select")[0].sumo.getSelStr().split(",")

var pattern = (arr.join('|'));

Comment: I do not understand very well what you want, is it?      https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/18/ ....

Comment: yes i want this but it doesn't work and i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

You have to search the datatable Filtering with regex expressions

after getting the value from sumoselect

1 : **the replace does not work as planned , it replaces the first comma with | and remaining it does not replace.**

*to over come this i used regex to replace all the comma value in pattern*

Try this link : https://jsfiddle.net/p2x1ge7v/2/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
 var office = $('#example').DataTable()
                .column(2)
                .data()
                .toArray();
     var officeunq = [];
        $.each(office, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, officeunq) === -1) 
    {officeunq.push(el);
     optionText =  $.trim(el);
    $('#select1').append(`<option value="${optionText}">
                                       ${optionText}
                                  </option>`);
    }
});
$('#select1').SumoSelect(); 
    $('#button').click( function () { 
     var pattern = $('#select1').val();
     if(pattern!=null)
     {pattern = pattern.toString().replace(/,/g, '|');
     $('#example').DataTable().destroy(); 
     alert(pattern);
     
$('#example').DataTable({ "search": {regex: true}}).column(2).search(pattern, true, false ).draw(); 
} else
    {
   
    $('#example').DataTable().search( '' )
 .columns().search( '' )
 .draw();
    }
    } ); 
    
   
} );
```